# Automatically scale the height of a flexbox to the height of the highest flexbox of the same row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How could we automatically scale the height of a flexbox to the height of the highest flexbox of the same row and make it return to regular size if not in the same row of the tall flexbox? I'm not sure about how I can explain this more, so there are pictures and a link to a codepen with my problem.

**Picture of what I have now:**
[image]

**Picture of what I would like it to look like:**

[image]

Is it possible to make that using html and CSS only? If not, is there a way to always make sure that the longest ones are the first ones in the row? If possible, can you say what's wrong or what I should change or add to achieve something that I want (partially or completely).

```css
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-around;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexItem {
   flex: auto;
   border-radius: 25px;
   border: 2px outset #b11313ab;
   padding: 20px; 
   min-width: 200px;
   max-width: 230px;
   width: fit-content;
   min-height: 150px;
   height: fit-content;
   margin: 5px;
   background-color: #b4b4b4;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <h1>Need help to auto adjust height, so all the same row have the same height</h1>
<a href=""><h2>Link to the discussion (and maybe the answer here)</h2></a>
    <section class="flexContainer">
        <div class="flexItem">
            <h2>Subject with a very, very, very, very, very long title</h2>
            <p>With a very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very,very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, long description...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flexItem">
            <h2>Subject</h2>
            <p>Description of the subject</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flexItem">
            <h2>Subject</h2>
            <p>Description of the subject</p>
        </div>
      <div class="flexItem">
            <h2>Subject</h2>
            <p>Description of the subject</p>
        </div>
      <div class="flexItem">
            <h2>Subject</h2>
            <p>Description of the subject</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flexItem">
            <h2>Subject</h2>
            <p>Description of the subject</p>
        </div>
      <div class="flexItem">
            <h2>Subject</h2>
            <p>Description of the subject</p>
        </div>
      <div class="flexItem">
            <h2>Subject</h2>
            <p>Description of the subject</p>
        </div>
      <div class="flexItem">
            <h2>Subject</h2>
            <p>Description of the subject</p>
        </div>
      <div class="flexItem">
            <h2>Subject</h2>
            <p>Description of the subject</p>
        </div>
       <div class="flexItem">
            <h2>Subject with a very, very, very, very, very long title</h2>
            <p>With a very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very,very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, long description...</p>
        </div>
      <div class="flexItem">
            <h2>Subject</h2>
            <p>Description of the subject</p>
        </div><div class="flexItem">
            <h2>Subject</h2>
            <p>Description of the subject</p>
        </div><div class="flexItem">
            <h2>Subject</h2>
            <p>Description of the subject</p>
        </div>
      <div class="flexItem">
            <h2>Subject</h2>
            <p>Description of the subject</p>
        </div><div class="flexItem">
            <h2>Subject</h2>
            <p>Description of the subject</p>
        </div><div class="flexItem">
            <h2>Subject</h2>
            <p>Description of the subject</p>
        </div>
      <div class="flexItem">
            <h2>Subject</h2>
            <p>Description of the subject</p>
        </div>
       <div class="flexItem">
            <h2>Subject with a very, very, very, very, very long title</h2>
            <p>With a very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very,very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, long description...</p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Here is a [link](https://codepen.io/Amachako/pen/yLPQdmr) to CodePen as well.

Comment: `display:flex` behaves exactly like you want if you hadn't set this `height: fit-content;` on `flexItem.`

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `min-height` and `height` in `.flexItem{...}`
and add this line of code instead:

```css
   height: max(fit-content, 200px);
```

Comment: Hi ashkan. It works even without that.

Comment: Even with that it doesn't work in my code, but it works in the codepen. And I can't find why it doesn't work (even after reloading CSS).

Answer (score 0):

`display:flex` behaves exactly like you want if you hadn't set this `height: fit-content;` on `flex-item`. Removing it does what you are looking for:

```css
.flexContainer {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-content: space-around;
   align-items: stretch;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexItem {
   flex: auto;
   border-radius: 25px;
   border: 2px outset #b11313ab;
   padding: 20px; 
   min-width: 200px;
   max-width: 230px;
   width: fit-content;
   min-height: 150px;
   margin: 5px;
   background-color: #b4b4b4;
}
```

```html
<main>
        <h1>Need help to auto adjust height, so all the same row have the same height</h1>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71321597/automatically-scale-the-height-of-a-flexbox-to-the-height-of-the-highest-flexbox"><h2>Link to the discussion (and maybe the answer here)</h2></a>
        <section class="flexContainer">
            <div class="flexItem">
                <h2>Subject with a very, very, very, very, very long title</h2>
                <p>With a very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very,very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, long description...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="flexItem">
                <h2>Subject</h2>
                <p>Description of the subject</p>
            </div>
            <div class="flexItem">
                <h2>Subject</h2>
                <p>Description of the subject</p>
            </div>
          <div class="flexItem">
                <h2>Subject</h2>
                <p>Description of the subject</p>
            </div>
          <div class="flexItem">
                <h2>Subject</h2>
                <p>Description of the subject</p>
            </div>
            <div class="flexItem">
                <h2>Subject</h2>
                <p>Description of the subject</p>
            </div>
          <div class="flexItem">
                <h2>Subject</h2>
                <p>Description of the subject</p>
            </div>
          <div class="flexItem">
                <h2>Subject</h2>
                <p>Description of the subject</p>
            </div>
          <div class="flexItem">
                <h2>Subject</h2>
                <p>Description of the subject</p>
            </div>
          <div class="flexItem">
                <h2>Subject</h2>
                <p>Description of the subject</p>
            </div>
           <div class="flexItem">
                <h2>Subject with a very, very, very, very, very long title</h2>
                <p>With a very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very,very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, long description...</p>
            </div>
          <div class="flexItem">
                <h2>Subject</h2>
                <p>Description of the subject</p>
            </div><div class="flexItem">
                <h2>Subject</h2>
                <p>Description of the subject</p>
            </div><div class="flexItem">
                <h2>Subject</h2>
                <p>Description of the subject</p>
            </div>
          <div class="flexItem">
                <h2>Subject</h2>
                <p>Description of the subject</p>
            </div><div class="flexItem">
                <h2>Subject</h2>
                <p>Description of the subject</p>
            </div><div class="flexItem">
                <h2>Subject</h2>
                <p>Description of the subject</p>
            </div>
          <div class="flexItem">
                <h2>Subject</h2>
                <p>Description of the subject</p>
            </div>
           <div class="flexItem">
                <h2>Subject with a very, very, very, very, very long title</h2>
                <p>With a very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very,very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, long description...</p>
            </div>
        </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height: fit-content` from `.flexItem`. Or set `height: auto` for that. although not need to that:

```css
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-around;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexItem {
  flex: auto;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px outset #b11313ab;
  padding: 20px;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 230px;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #b4b4b4;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Need help to auto adjust height, so all the same row have the same height</h1>
  <a href="">
    <h2>Link to the discussion (and maybe the answer here)</h2>
  </a>
  <section class="flexContainer">
    <div class="flexItem">
      <h2>Subject with a very, very, very, very, very long title</h2>
      <p>With a very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very,very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very,
        very, very, long description...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
      <h2>Subject</h2>
      <p>Description of the subject</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
      <h2>Subject</h2>
      <p>Description of the subject</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
      <h2>Subject</h2>
      <p>Description of the subject</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
      <h2>Subject</h2>
      <p>Description of the subject</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
      <h2>Subject</h2>
      <p>Description of the subject</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
      <h2>Subject</h2>
      <p>Description of the subject</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
      <h2>Subject</h2>
      <p>Description of the subject</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
      <h2>Subject</h2>
      <p>Description of the subject</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
      <h2>Subject</h2>
      <p>Description of the subject</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
      <h2>Subject with a very, very, very, very, very long title</h2>
      <p>With a very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very,very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very,
        very, very, long description...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
      <h2>Subject</h2>
      <p>Description of the subject</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
      <h2>Subject</h2>
      <p>Description of the subject</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
      <h2>Subject</h2>
      <p>Description of the subject</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
      <h2>Subject</h2>
      <p>Description of the subject</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
      <h2>Subject</h2>
      <p>Description of the subject</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
      <h2>Subject</h2>
      <p>Description of the subject</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
      <h2>Subject</h2>
      <p>Description of the subject</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
      <h2>Subject with a very, very, very, very, very long title</h2>
      <p>With a very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very,very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very,
        very, very, long description...</p>
    </div>
  </section>
```